# How to find the virtual memory address size in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, virtual

I need to find the virtual address size supported in my PC running Linux Ubuntu. Following is my kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 2.6.28-11-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 01:57:59 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I also ran 'free' to know this, as per some earlier posts in this forum:

```
***@ubuntu:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2963968     740752    2223216          0     217648     360296
-/+ buffers/cache:     162808    2801160
Swap:       262136          0     262136
```

However, the value that I obtained is not a power of 2, as I had expected.

Please let me know the correct way to obtain the total virtual memory address space. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just what do you mean by "virtual memory address space"? Maybe you want to know if your OS is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Also, how is this related to programming? Looks like it's just generic computer / Linux question, there are other SE sites for questions like this.

Comment: Virtual address size is either 32 or 64 bits. Virtual memory size depends on your swap file/partition size and doesn't have to be a power of 2. Available physical memory size, contrary to some naïve expectations, is almost never a power of 2 either. Not all physical memory installed in your system is available to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

`cat /proc/meminfo`

You will get a list of information

You can see`VmallocTotal`, is the size of total virtual memory allocated.